# Unity errors after updating

Tags: unity-game-engine

l updated unity and now l am having the following error log.

```
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\Omer\Documents\New Unity Project\Packages\com.unity.package-manager-ui\Editor\Sources\Services\Interfaces\IOperationFactory.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\Omer\Documents\New Unity Project\Packages\com.unity.package-manager-ui\Editor\Sources\Services\Packages\PackageOrigin.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\Omer\Documents\New Unity Project\Packages\com.unity.package-manager-ui\Editor\Sources\UI\PackageItem.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\Omer\Documents\New Unity Project\Packages\com.unity.package-manager-ui\Editor\Sources\Services\Packages\PackageGroupOrigins.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\Omer\Documents\New Unity Project\Packages\com.unity.package-manager-ui\Editor\Sources\UI\Common\Alert.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\Omer\Documents\New Unity Project\Packages\com.unity.package-manager-ui\Editor\Sources\UI\PackageDetails.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\Omer\Documents\New Unity Project\Packages\com.unity.package-manager-ui\Editor\Sources\Services\Packages\PackageState.cs'.
```

Comment: What kind of update? Unity? What was the old version and what is the new version? Some package you have installed? What is it called? You might consider editing your question to format it a little better.

Comment: 2017 to 2018 and i am beginner in unity so when i was scripting using 2017 version there wasn't any package error but after updating to 2018 whenever i am scripting using visual studio it is giving me errors.I just download from official website.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete and to reinstall your all your packages, this will install the latest version of the package optimized for the unity latest version.

You can use the package manager windows to do this. If this is not working you just have to come back to your old unity version.

PS: Do not forget to restart unity after reinstalling all packages.

Answer (score 1):

This issue that you are facing is because Unity resolved the packages after Unity update but could not compile them correctly.

To fix this, just delete the `PackageCache` folder inside the `Library` folder of your `Unity Project` while having Unity Editor closed and then When you re-open Unity, it will re-download those package files.

Just delete - `C:\Users\Omer\Documents\New Unity Project\Library\PackageCahce\`

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me too, i tried to restart or even reinstall unity, but it seems that the only way to avoid this error is by deleting and reimporting the packages

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, the easiest way to fix this is to delete all the caches so Unity will re-download and compile them again.

1. Make sure Unity is closed.
2. Delete the `Library` folder from your project. In your case just delete `C:\Users\Omer\Documents\New Unity Project\Library`
3. Delete the AppData cache. Search `%appdata%` in the Windows search, delete the packages folder in roaming - `AppData\Roaming\Unity\Packages`. Also delete the packages folder in the local folder - `AppData\Local\Unity\cache\packages`
4. Restart Unity and wait for it to re-download and compile the packages, this should fix the errors.